# Angular2 ngModel select - handling an object

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following construct:

```
 <select ngbDropDown class="form-control" id="disk1" required [(ngModel)]="disk1" name="resourceA">
     <option *ngFor="let r of disks" [value]="r">{{r.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

I want to pass the r object to the ngModel disk1, which is a property in my component:

```
disk1 = new Disk();
```

However if I try to access it after changing the select box I get undefined:

```
console.log("Disk1 id: " + this.disk1.id);
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: are `disk1` and `disks` meant to be same object ?

Comment: can we assign objects to [value]? i am doubt on that

Comment: @candidJ disk1 and disks are 2 different properties in my component. disks is  to retrieve items from a webserver and disk1 is to save the actual value from the select box.

Comment: @RavinSinghD that's also my uncertainty whether that works. If I'm using a property in ngModel disk1.id and also use [value]="r.id" then it works. But I'd like to handover the whole object.

Comment: @nehemia is `id` an property on `disk1` that you  want to access ?

Comment: @candidJ exactly, I would like to access all properties from disk1 then, as soon as this object is being passed from the <option>-Element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngValue` instead of the simple value binding to bind an object to the `option` element.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.selectedItem" name="selectItem">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item">{{item.title}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Couldn't find anything related to ngValue in the API ref in Angular2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/# Any hints?

Comment: Curiously I couldn't find anything in the documentation either, but it works for me :) Found that solution some time ago on stackoverflow as well.

Comment: For future reference: [docs for ngValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor)

Answer (score 0):

You could use functions on click for the option and assign the selected with a function in your component, like this:

```
<select ngbDropDown class="form-control" id="disk1" required [(ngModel)]="disk1" name="resourceA">
     <option *ngFor="let r of disks" [value]="r" (click)="selected(r)">{{r.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

in your component you should have something like this:

```
.Class({
   constructor: function() {},
   selected: function(element){
     this.disk1 = { name:"MyDisk", content: element.content, id: element.id };
   }
})
```

Comment: That would probably work. However is ngModel meant only for properties and not whole objects to pass?

Comment: You could create an object property, I updated the answer to show you. Please mark as answered your question if this answer your question.

Comment: @nehemia, yes ngModel is bound to one property at a time. In your case you bind it to disk id and find your object from disks collection that you have in component.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Hope it helps:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="disk1" required>
     <option *ngFor="let r of disks" [value]="r">{{r.name}}</option>
</select>
```